# python - find xpath of element containing string

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, lxml

I build a small script that supposed to find some specific string in a page and return the xpath of the element containing this string.
The purpose is to use this xpath for finding string with same context.

I'm using this code:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
page = requests.get("http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/")
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
result = tree.xpath('//*[. = "XML"]')
```

`result[0]` returns `<Element b at 0x7f034a08e940>` and I can't figure out how to find this element's XPath anyway .

The string I would like to have is:

```
/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]
```

Comment: xpath subpage is now moved to https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`getpath()`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html#getpath) to get xpath from `element`, for example :

```
import requests
from lxml import html

page = requests.get("http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/")
root = html.fromstring(page.text)
tree = root.getroottree()
result = root.xpath('//*[. = "XML"]')
for r in result:
    print(tree.getpath(r))
```

Output :

```
/html/body/div[3]/div/ul/li[10]
/html/body/div[3]/div/ul/li[10]/a
/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]
/html/body/div[5]/div/div[6]/h3
/html/body/div[6]/div/div[4]/h3
/html/body/div[7]/div/div[4]/h3
```

Comment: I tried your code with URL : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp. Actually there are 8 elements include XML string but script returns only 7 Element. Maybe because of the Panel?