# Write a python script to find out the XPath from the HTML based on any class

Tags: python, web-scraping, scripting

In Python, I want the user to enter a URL in the console prompt (take input and store it in some variable), 
**For example, if the webpage contains this HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1 class="class_one">First heading</h1>
                <p>Some text</p>
            <div class="class_two">
                <div class="class_three">
                    <div class="class_one">
                        <center class="class_two">
                            <h3 class="class_three">
                            </h3>
                        </center>
                        <center>
                            <h3 class="find_first_class">
                                Some text
                            </h3>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="class_two">
                <div class="class_three">
                    <div class="class_one">
                        <center class="class_two">
                            <h2 class="find_second_class">
                            </h2>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then the CSV should contain rows for each and every class that's in the HTML of the webpage (since classes can appear more than once, so we could have multiple rows for any given class).

Now, I want to generate XPath for all the classes present on the page.
What i have written so far is :

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = {}
user_url_list = raw_input("Please enter your urls separated by spaces : \n")
url_list = map(str, user_url_list.split())
for url in url_list:
    try:
        page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
        user_class_list = raw_input("Please enter the classes to parse for " + url + " separated by spaces : \n")
        class_list = map(str, user_class_list.split())
        for find_class in class_list:
            try:
                name_box = soup.find(attrs={'class': find_class})
                print(xpath_soup(name_box))
                break
            except:
                print("There was some error getting the xpath of class : " + find_class + " for url : " + url + "\n..trying next class now \n")
                continue
    except:
        print(url + " is not valid, please enter correct full url \n")
        continue
print(result)
```

Comment: You could use xpath in simple 'try except' blok for your first and second class.I think no need to waste time to checking spesific content in webpage.

Comment: @OrhanSolak Thanks for your feedback, issue is i never worked on python and web-scraping, i want to learn it but right now i was looking for some script (due to urgency of work) from where i can start with, i will definetly dig deeper later on.

Comment: This [link](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-scrape-websites-with-python-and-beautifulsoup-5946935d93fe) could be helpful. Even if you read only the highlighted part, you'll be able to do your work just in minutes.

Comment: @OrhanSolak thanks a lot, i read it, but i cannot find how to find the xpath of that node like : /div[1]/div[2]/center[2]/h3[1], can you please guide me on how to find the xpath

Comment: Try this : **$x("normalize-space(//div[@class='class_two']//div[@class='class_one']//h3[@class='find_first_class'])")**  if you copy paste this code to console(press F12 in chrome) the output would be **Some text** between the _h3_. By the way, **normalize-space** just shows you the _output as a readable text format_, do not use this part while writing code in python.

Comment: @OrhanSolak thanks man but i am still figuring our how to find xpath the code that i have written so far is i edited in question.Idea is to get some classes from user and store all the xpaths of that class into some variable, but we also need to identify the correct xpath like if we find a class at two places then we need to store two entries into that list like so :
/div[1]/div[2]/cente[2]/h3[1] and 
/div[2]/idv[3]/center[1]/h3[4]

Comment: I understood what do you want to try. We need to take *some kind of classes from user* and assign to a variable (probably you'll use later.) With this code as you wrote, you can only get _one_ class name and you could not know the exact location(respectively) this **class name** in a html tree. The most healthy way (according to me) is taking **exact string name(Some text)** from user and try to find this text's xpath. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29890301/python-find-xpath-of-element-containing-string) could be helpful

Comment: @OrhanSolak thanks man for sticking up with me, we got it resolved

Comment: It's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the try/except logic Orhan mentioned. lxml parses the document it is passed and can reference the elements via xpath and extract the classes. After that it is just a simple check if they occur in the desired classes. lxml also allows the reconstruction of the initial xpath via ElementTree.

```
import csv
import requests
from lxml import etree

target_url = input('Which url is to be scraped?')

page = '''
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1 class="class_one">First heading</h1>
                <p>Some text</p>
            <div class="class_two">
                <div class="class_three">
                    <div class="class_one">
                        <center class="class_two">
                            <h3 class="class_three">
                            </h3>
                        </center>
                        <center>
                            <h3 class="find_first_class">
                                Some text
                            </h3>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="class_two">
                <div class="class_three">
                    <div class="class_one">
                        <center class="class_two">
                            <h2 class="find_second_class">
                            </h2>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
'''

#response = requests.get(target_url)
#document = etree.parse(response.content)
classes_list = ['find_first_class', 'find_second_class']
expressions = []

document = etree.fromstring(page)

for element in document.xpath('//*'):
    try:
        ele_class = element.xpath("@class")[0]
        print(ele_class)
        if ele_class in classes_list:
            tree = etree.ElementTree(element)
            expressions.append((ele_class, tree.getpath(element)))
    except IndexError:
        print("No class in this element.")
        continue

with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(expressions)
```

Comment: Good job friend :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking similar thing here is how i made it work :

```
import os
import csv
import requests
from lxml import html


csv_file = raw_input("Enter CSV file name\n")
full_csv_file = os.path.abspath(csv_file)
with open(full_csv_file) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = [temp_reader for temp_reader in reader]
    final_result = {}

    for item_list in data:
        class_locations = {}
        url = item_list[0]
        item_list.pop(0)
        try:
            page = requests.get(url)
            root = html.fromstring(page.text)
            tree = root.getroottree()
            for find_class in item_list:
                find_class_locations =[]
                try:
                    result = root.xpath("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' " + find_class + " ')]")
                    for r in result:
                        find_class_locations.append(tree.getpath(r))
                    class_locations[find_class] = find_class_locations
                except Exception,e:
                    print(e)
                    continue
            final_result[url] = class_locations
        except Exception, e:
            print(e)
            continue
print(final_result)
```